# Run function inside a thread and get result

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have 2 functions that can tell me if a file is in use by checking if the size of the file grows.In order to work I need to use a delay of 5000ms between each size gathered from the same file.This is OK but it blocks my main thread so I have to put the functions inside a thread. Here are the functions that I use. How can I create a thread in which I execute the functions and get the result? Below are the functions that I'm used at the moment. Thank!

```
function GetFileSize_mmg(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;


function does_size_changes(filename:string; delay:integer;memo_loguri:Tmemo): boolean;
var size1,size2:int64;
begin
result:=false;
size1:=GetFileSize_mmg(filename);
sleep(delay);
size2:= GetFileSize_mmg(filename);

if size1 <> size2 then
begin
result:=true;
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - file "'+filename+'" is growing: ' +inttostr(size1)+' < '+inttostr(size2));
end

else
begin
result:=false;
memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now)+' - file "'+filename+'" can be used: '+ inttostr(size1)+' = '+inttostr(size2));
end;
end;
```

Comment: Rather than query the file size over time, why not simply ask the OS if the file is in use?  You could try opening the file in exclusive mode and see if a sharing violation error occurs.  Or use the [`IFileIsInUse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775874.aspx) interface.

Comment: I've already tried that. Works ok under all OS tested except the storage were the files are being exported from 3rd party software. It's a custom OS built for cluster storage. It appears that there is a bug inside the server OS. I've already talked to the server administrator and warned him about the big security issue regarding file locks(i was able to delete a file while it was being written from another application.) Untill the administrator fixes that problem I have to change my application so that I can test the files before processing them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to make this work and syncronize the gui with the result. In one listbox I keep the files that are in use and in another listbox i keep the files that can be procesed. The following thread solves the problem with the gui freezing and also it takes only 5 seconds to process all files. I load all files into a listbox(listbox_fisiere_in_uz). I check the files using the thread bellow. If the files are not growing in size then I move them to the second listbox(ListBox_fisiere_restore_vme).

```
function GetFileSize_mmg(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;

type
  TThread_verificare_fisiere_in_uz = class(TThread)
  private
   Variabila_fisier: string;
   variabila_interval_verificare:integer;
    size1, size2: Int64;
    raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier:string;
    test_raspuns:string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure AfisareRezultat;
  public
    constructor Create(nume_fisier:string;interval:integer);
  end;



constructor TThread_verificare_fisiere_in_uz.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  Variabila_fisier := nume_fisier;
  variabila_interval_verificare:= interval;
end;

procedure TThread_verificare_fisiere_in_uz.Execute;
begin

  raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier := 'false';
  size1 := GetFileSize_mmg(Variabila_fisier);
  sleep(variabila_interval_verificare);
  size2 := GetFileSize_mmg(Variabila_fisier);



  if size1 <> size2 then
  begin
    raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier := 'true';
    test_raspuns:='Fisierul '+Variabila_fisier+' este in curs de scriere:'+inttostr(size1)+'<>'+inttostr(size2);
     Synchronize(AfisareRezultat);
  end;

  if size1 = size2 then
  begin
    raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier := 'false';
     test_raspuns:='Fisierul '+Variabila_fisier+' nu este in uz'+inttostr(size1)+'='+inttostr(size2);
     Synchronize(AfisareRezultat);
  end;

end;


procedure TThread_verificare_fisiere_in_uz.AfisareRezultat;
var index_fisier_verificat:integer;
    fisier_in_curs_de_verificare:string;
    raspuns:string;

begin
{detectez index-ul fisierului in curs de verificare dupa numele fisierului pe care il verific}
index_fisier_verificat:= form2.ListBox_fisiere_in_uz.Items.IndexOf(variabila_fisier);
fisier_in_curs_de_verificare:= variabila_fisier;
raspuns:= raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier;

 if raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier = 'true' then
  begin
    Form2.Memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now) +
        ' - dimensiunea fisierului "' + fisier_in_curs_de_verificare + '" creste: ' + inttostr
        (size1) + ' < ' + inttostr(size2) +
        ' => fisierul este in proces de scriere');

  end;

  if raspuns_verificare_stare_fisier = 'false' then
  begin
    Form2.Memo_loguri.Lines.Add(datetimetostr(now) +
        ' - dimensiunea fisierului "' + fisier_in_curs_de_verificare + '" nu se modifica: ' +
        inttostr(size1) + ' = ' + inttostr(size2)
        + ' => fisierul nu este in uz');
    begin


if not exista_textul_in_listbox(Form2.ListBox_fisiere_in_uz.Items[index_fisier_verificat],Form2.ListBox_fisiere_restore_vme) then
        Form2.ListBox_fisiere_restore_vme.Items.Add(Form2.ListBox_fisiere_in_uz.Items[index_fisier_verificat]);


if Form2.ListBox_fisiere_in_uz.Items.count > 0 then Form2.ListBox_fisiere_in_uz.Items.Delete(index_fisier_verificat);
    end
  end;

end;
```

Comment: `index_element_verificat:= i;` is not correct in TThread_verificare_fisiere_in_uz.Create; Pass the value as a parameter in the create constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. Stop using threads and replace with a timer with 5000ms interval.
2. Use a shared event object for thread safe signaling.
3. Use a shared boolean. This will have a data race but a benign one.
4. Post a message to the main thread as notification.
5. Use `TThread.Synchronize` for synchronous notification.

Comment: Could you please post an exemple on how to make such a thread?

Comment: Why don't you pick option 1 and keep it simple?

Comment: Because I already have a timer on the main form that fires at every 50 seconds.

Comment: So add a second timer that fires every 5s.

Comment: OK. This function is used inside a loop in order to check if all the files from a listbox are in user or not ( their size grows or not).So it will block my main form for 5 seconds at every call

Comment: What do you know about threads? On the face of it, it almost looks as though you want somebody to write your code for you. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I know how to create a simple thread but i don't know how to pass to it the variables i need: the filename and how to extract the result of the calculation. I don't know how to tell the thread which filename to use for calculations.

Comment: Pass the variables as parameters of the constructor. Use `TThread.Synchronize` to send data back to the main thread. Or indeed any one of the other methods that I suggested.

Comment: So i guess it's something like this:

type
  TTestThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FVariable: string;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(Variable: string);
  end;

constructor TTest.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FVariable := Form1.listbox.items[i];
end;

procedure TThread.Execute;
begin
  //code that i need
end;

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the right direction. I'm not expecting for someone to write me the code but i just needed a pointing direction.

Comment: Instead of `FVariable := Form1.listbox.items[i]` you make the rhs of the assignment be the parameter that was passed.  Your thread shouldn't really know anything at all about the GUI.

Comment: @user2858981 Unless your list box has a particularly large number of files, using a thread to check file sizes is overkill. I'm pretty certain your only reasonable option is #1. All you need to do is keep a list of sizes the last time you checked, and compare when you re-check in the `OnTimer` event.

Comment: @David Isn't there an option 6 to register for notifications from ShellAPI? If the list of files is particularly large, that may be the better option.

Comment: @CraigYoung If you follow the previous questions from this user, it seems that the file modifications are happening on a remote server that doesn't even lock the files. So I doubt it.